# Eclipse how to send a message to a view?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

I want to write a manage program, the core manager thread can control the display of views etc, but how to make it?
  Are there any message notify mechanism in eclipse to do this work?

Answer (score 1):

IPropertyChangeListener!

Using IPropertyChangeListener can realize my demand, it can be a bridge to any elements, from a ui to ui, from a background job to a ui part or any other relation, so with this interface, we can use a job to get data from remote server, then notify the ui views to update it's contents.
[this link shows that how to use IPropertyChangeListener](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/)

Comment: I got this solution, maybe it's my fault that not describe clearly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken. However, the article is still available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20121231080758/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to share Data between multiple instances by binding it to the shell:

Setter:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setData(key, value);
```

Getter:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().getData(key);
```